# Python & Neo4j Heroku Installation

Tags: python, heroku, neo4j

I am in the process of setting up a python install on Heroku.  I am following the Heroku instructions.  My question is after the Python install how do I integrate or connect with neo4j?  My skill level is beginner.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these examples:

neoblog 
Description: A very simply blog application using a neo4j database. You can make posts and link similar ones together.

http://gensen.herokuapp.com/show/26

python, flask, neo4j demo app 
Description: This app uses neo4j to explore Stack Exchange data from their commons data dump. The app is constructed using the Flask microframework for Python and uses py2neo for access to the neo4j data. Read the project README or the documentation URL for more information.

http://gensen.herokuapp.com/show/25

see also http://py2neo.org/ for general advice

Comment: the herokuapp seems to be dead or down?